# Como verificar se um método existe numa classe em Python?

Tags: python, classes, método

Como verificar se um método existe numa classe em Python?

Existe alguma função que faça isso?

```
class Test(object):
    def method(self):
          pass
```

Por exemplo, gostaria de verificar através de uma condição se determinado método existe para chamá-lo caso exista.

Comment: As respostas dessas pergunta tratá todos os métodos da classe. Não era a minha intenção, queria realmente saber se um método específico existe ou não, da mesma forma que se faz em PHP com `method_exists('Class', 'method')`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic veja a minha resposta e talvez mudará de ideia quando a duplicata.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não, retorna `True` para ambos. Eu mantive ela como solução 2 na minha resposta.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic para atributos *normais*, funciona! O problema é quando há composição de classes e o atributo é uma instância de uma classe `callable`. O teste passa a retornar `True` para este atributo sem ser um método.

Answer (score 6):

#### Problema:

Consideremos o seguinte contexto:

```
class Call:
    def __call__(self):
        pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = Call()

    def method(self):
        pass

foo = Foo()
```

Ou seja, temos um objeto `foo` que é uma instância de `Foo`, possuindo um método `method` e um atributo `var`, que é do tipo `Call` (que é *callable*). Ao se verificar se um método existe, esperamos que apenas `method` seja retornado como válido e `var` não.

#### Solução 1:

> **Spolier alert:** Não utilizar! :(

Proposta por Wallace, em sua resposta (adaptada):

```
def method_exists(instance, method):
    return hasattr(instance, method) and callable(instance.method)
```

Fazendo os testes para o problema:

```
>>> print(method_exists(foo, "method"))
True
>>> print(method_exists(foo, "var"))
True
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/BweL0d)</sup>

Ou seja, a solução **falhou** no segundo teste.

#### Solução 2:

> **Spolier alert:** Não utilizar! :(

Proposta por mim, em uma versão anterior a esta resposta:

```
def method_exists(instance, method):
    return method in dir(instance) and callable(instance.method)
```

Fazendo os testes para o problema:

```
>>> print(method_exists(foo, "method"))
True
>>> print(method_exists(foo, "var"))
True
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/JZCfh1)</sup>

Ou seja, a solução também **falhou** no segundo teste.

#### Solução 3:

> **Spolier alert:** Funciona! Pode usar :D

Proposta também por Wallace em sua resposta (adaptada):

```
from inspect import ismethod

def method_exists(instance, method):
    return hasattr(instance, method) and ismethod(getattr(instance, method))
```

Fazendo os testes para o problema:

```
>>> print(method_exists(foo, "method"))
True
>>> print(method_exists(foo, "var"))
False
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ou0k4u)</sup>

Portanto, passou nos dois testes.

> Na solução 3, necessitou-se da inclusão da função `getattr` para a verificação se é um método.

Comment: Muito bom +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função chamada `hasattr` para saber se uma determinada propriedade existe na classe e em seguida usar `callable` caso a propriedade exista para saber se é algo "invocável" (no caso o método):

```
class Test(object):
    def x(self):
        pass



if hasattr(Test, 'x') and callable(Test.x):
    print ("Método 'x' existe")
```

É possível também usar a biblioteca `inspect` para poder checar se determinado atributo de uma classe é um método.

```
 from inspect import ismethod

 if hasattr(Test, 'x') and ismethod(Test.x):
     print ("Tem 'x'")
```